# Undo, revert !important, fall back to inline style?

Tags: css

Given this code (HTML with stylesheet), which I **can not** change:

```css
div {
  color: green !important;
}

div {
  color: undo; /* tried revert/initial/unset et al. */
}
```

```html
<div style="color: red">hello</div>
```

can I supply a stylesheet (appended, added on top of the original stylesheet) which turns the div back to the inline color (in this case red)?

```css
div {
  color: undo; /* tried revert/initial/unset et al. */
}
```

...without JS. Here's [a pen](https://codepen.io/bikubi/pen/ZEepggL).

Note: this is not about red specifically, but falling back to whichever color is supplied inline.

Comment: What about find&replace all `!important` from your stylesheet? Or using regex remove all `!important` rules? Construction `inline style, non-working CSS rule and another undo rule` is way to the coding hell.

Comment: @pavel the style the OP is trying to override is inline style

Comment: @ProsyArceno `Given this code, which I can't change:` the OP can not change the HTML code

Comment: @pavel - I can't change neither the original HTML nor the original stylesheet, I can only add stylesheets. This is not a question about best practices, coding styles & what to avoid in general.

Comment: Can you remove it entirely (the stylesheet), no JS, right?

Comment: @CornelRaiu - I am not trying to *override* the inline style, I am trying to "override" the `!important` and get *back* to the inline style.

Comment: with pure css, I don't think so.

Comment: !important can only be override with !important if the selector's specifity is at least equal and standing after the first one `div {color: initial!important;}` ,but it won't go back to red.

Comment: @prettyInPink - good idea, but no. And it wouldn't answer the question, which I would be still curious about.

Comment: @kubi with pure CSS, you can only override it by mentioning the color you want it to go back to with the !important attribute. I don't know of any general CSS rule that would revert to the inline style.

Comment: Pure out of curiosity, which (presumably) CMS is being used in this case?

Comment: @prettyInPink I deliberately did not mention it, to avoid "oh that pile of garbage" / "just use something else" comments :) the CMS in question isn't the worst offender here, I have seen similar patterns in many new/fancy frameworks, too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible. The inline style has lost in the cascade to the !important style and the information is gone.

Adding further styles can't bring it back. The closest is `revert` which erases the styles of an origin but does not distinguish for importance, so can't erase important styles while leaving normal styles alone.